# sharing global variables across modules combined with from module import *

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) a clear way to share variables across modules.
Accordingly, my code is set up like this:

**config.py**

```
def init():
     global x
```

**mod.py**

```
import config
def set_globals(month):
    config.x = month
```

**main.py**

```
import config
config.init()
import mod
mod.set_globals(2)
print(config.x)
```

Now, this is just a MWE.  In the real case, I have lots of variables to share between modules - not just `x`.  And **mod.py** actually reads a file to get these values and store them in variables.

**main.py** is designed set the environment and then drop the user into interactive mode, so that the user can play around with these functions and these variables.

My question is: can I simplify the variable names so that I don't need to use `config.x` but simply `x`?  I know I can use something like this: `import config as g` and then refer to `g.x`.  But I'd like to make it even simpler.

But when I try `from config import *`, I always get errors about variables not being defined.  Is it possible?

And as a related question, given that global variables are somewhat evil™, is the method of sharing variables presented in the link in my top sentence also evil?

Comment: As an aside, `global x` in `config.py` does nothing and is completely pointless.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it better now? I put inside a function.

Comment: No, that is even more pointless, since `init` *does nothing*. It simply returns `None`. Literally all you would need is an empty module.